# how to generate sample swf file using AS3

Tags: file, air, adobe, flash, format

is possible that I can create an Adobe AIR application to generate sample shape and save it as swf file?

I know how to create shape, color, save it as image, but I want the output to be vector file like what flash can create, swf file format.

thanks!

Comment: Have a look at AS3SWF (https://github.com/claus/as3swf)

Answer (score 0):

Try AS3SWF.
[AS3 to SWF](https://github.com/claus/as3swf)
You can generate and save swf files from as3 (check out the examples folder once you download the code)