# how to export movieclip as swf?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a movieclip loaded I modify and show in swf loader in flash builder 4.5 project,

I want the user to be able to save the movieclip to his disk as swf is there a straight

forward way to do that?

I searched for suggestions and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482053/as3-export-a-movieclip-or-canves-to-swf) but nothing seems to work

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903227/how-to-generate-sample-swf-file-using-as3

Answer (score 0):

completed the project finally thanks to the ["AS3SWF" class](https://github.com/claus/as3swf)

here is how I save my files after importing the library to my project

```
    import com.codeazur.as3swf.SWF;

    var swf:SWF = new SWF(mySwfMc.loaderInfo.bytes);

    var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    swf.publish(ba);

    var C:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    C.position = 0;
    C.writeBytes(ba);
    var f:FileReference = new FileReference  ;

    f.save(C,"demo.swf");
```